# MVVM with Windows Forms

Tags: wpf, vb.net, winforms, mvvm, data-binding

The MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) pattern is usually used in WPF applications to provide a convenient way to use the databinding feature very efficiently.

I am using the MVVM pattern in a Windows Forms application which works out quite well so far. However in some cases I have an issue with databinding on Windows Forms controls:
Say i bind the Value Property of a standard date-time picker to the CurrentDate Property of my ViewModel via

```
dtpMyDateTimePicker.DataBindings.Add("Value", mViewModel, "CurrentDate")
```

, the Property is only updated when the control looses focus. Looking at how the dateTime picker works, by clicking on the "Arrow" symbol you can open a calender and scroll through months/years. While i would like to update my form constantly when scrolling through different dates the databinding only updates the Property of my viewModel when i select a date and close the calendar tool.

A more simple example would be databinding on the Text Property of a Textbox (imagine a search field) - the method for databinding which i am currently using does not allow to constantly update my form while typing.

Obviously i can implement the _ValueChanged events of the controls on my Form and update the Properties of the ViewModel manually. However this takes the whole magic out of the MVVM pattern since i am now only using one-way databinding (ViewModel -> View) and need to implement logic (change events) in the form again.

TLDR: So basically i am looking for a way to specify some kind of UpdateSourceTrigger in Windows Forms applications.

Do you have any suggestions how to do this "properly"?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent `UpdateSourceTrigger` in Windows Forms is `DataSourceUpdateMode`. You can specify this for a separate `Binding` (and add this Binding to `DataBindings`) or you can also specify this via another overload of `DataBindings.Add()` method which accepts the fifth argument as `DataSourceUpdateMode`:

```
dtpMyDateTimePicker.DataBindings.Add("Value", mViewModel, "CurrentDate", true,
                                      DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```